# Centering equation between separate, largish xypic diagrams isn't working

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to typeset an equation in display mode between a pair of diagrams generated by `\xymatrix`, where these diagrams have been centered vertically on the line using `\vcenter`. The equation as a whole is wider than the textwidth, so I want to center it. I can't find a good solution how to do this, and the two things I've used elsewhere don't work. I can't really break it up into two lines, as I've got more complex examples for which I'm not sure it would work (in an `\align` multi-line environment, with the same ingredients, for instance). I'm working with a journal-provided template, and the ams packages in the MWE below are as provided, I'm not sure I can change those (even if reloading them does little).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts} %these are all as provided, I can't change these

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\xymatrix{#1}}}} % also breaks without the \hbox
\newcommand{\equals}{\quad=\quad}  

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\[
% \centerline{%  doesn't work
% \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%  also doesn't work
\hspace{-2cm} % works, but is bad
\diagram{xxxxxxxxxx \ar[r] & xxxx \ar@/^1.5pc/[r] \ar@/_1.5pc/[r] & xxx }
\equals
\diagram{&& xxxxx \ar[dr] \\
    xxxxxxxxxx \ar@/^/[urr] 
    \ar@/_/[drr] \ar[r] & 
    v^{[2]} \ar[ur] \ar[dr] && xxx\\
    && xxxxx \ar[ur]}%
% }
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the interaction between the `\vcenter` and the horizontal alignment commands I'm trying, but that is kinda the point. The MWE example currently gives what I want, but not *how* I want it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not so difficult to center an oversized equation, but I'd recommend splitting it across lines.

Instead of `\vcenter`, use `gathered`, which employs the same mechanism, but in a more user friendly way.

I redefined `\diagram` to also accept options for `\xymatrix`; so I can reduce a bit the gap between columns and get a slightly less wide object.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts} %these are all as provided, I can't change these

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\diagram}{}% to be sure it isn't defined
\def\diagram#1#{\diagramaux{#1}}% collect everything up to the first {
\newcommand\diagramaux[2]{\begin{gathered}\xymatrix#1{#2}\end{gathered}}

\newcommand{\equals}{\quad=\quad}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\[
\hspace{1000pt minus 2000pt}
\diagram@C-8pt{xxxxxxxxxx \ar[r] & xxxx \ar@/^1.5pc/[r] \ar@/_1.5pc/[r] & xxx }
\equals
\diagram@C-8pt{&& xxxxx \ar[dr] \\
    xxxxxxxxxx \ar@/^/[urr]
    \ar@/_/[drr] \ar[r] &
    v^{[2]} \ar[ur] \ar[dr] && xxx\\
    && xxxxx \ar[ur]}
\hspace{1000pt minus 2000pt}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The trick is to have flexible glue on either side. The big natural size tells TeX to squeeze the spaces as much as possible (nothing done, actually, in this case); but then the large shrink components do the job of centering with no overfull.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It works for some, but in places I'd already split it (using `align*`) and this method dies.

Answer (score 2):

I,m not familiar with `xy` package, so I use `tikz-cd` which is also intended for such diagrams. However, problem is the same at both diagrams.

For centering your "equations! in center of text, you can use `changepage` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}%{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd} %these are all as provided, I can't change these

%\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\xymatrix{#1}}}} % also breaks without the \hbox
\newcommand{\equals}{\quad=\quad}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-6em}{-6em}
\centering
    \begin{tikzcd}[baseline]
xxxxxxxxxx \ar[r]   & xxxx \ar[r, bend left] &  xxx \ar[l,bend left]
    \end{tikzcd}%
\equals%
    \begin{tikzcd}[baseline=-1ex]
        &   & xxxxx \ar[dr]          &       \\
xxxxxxxxxx \ar[r] \ar[urr,bend left]
                  \ar[drr, bend right]    
        &  v^{[2]}\ar[ur]  
                  \ar[dr] 
            &               & xxx   \\
        &   & xxxxx \ar[ur] &        
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You can merge bot diagrams in one and reduce separation between nodes. After this this equation become narrower:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}%{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd} %these are all as provided, I can't change these

%\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\xymatrix{#1}}}} % also breaks without the \hbox
\newcommand{\equals}{\quad=\quad}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.4em}{-2.4em}
%\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    \centering%
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
    &   &   &   &   & xxx \ar[dr]
                        &           \\
xxxxxxxxxx \ar[r]   
    & xxxx \ar[r, bend left] 
        & xxx\equals \ar[l,bend left]
            &   \hspace{-1.5em}
                xxxxxxxxxx \ar[r] \ar[urr,bend left] \ar[drr, bend right]    
                &  v^{[2]}  \ar[ur] \ar[dr] 
                    &   & xxx       \\
    &   &   &   &   & xxxxx \ar[ur] 
                        &        
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]